# memcpy CString to char*

Tags: c++, memcpy

I'm trying to copy a `CString` to a `char*` using `memcpy()` and I have difficulties doing it. In fact, only the first character is copied. Here is my code:

```
CString str = _T("something");
char* buff  = new char();

memcpy(buff, str, str.GetLength() + 1);
```

After this, all that `buff` contains is the letter `s`.

Comment: Don't you want `strcpy`?

Comment: You are only allocating space for 1 `char`. You are then trying to copy the `CString` object, rather than its contained buffer.

Comment: Be careful, `_T()` can create UNICODE strings based on `wchar_t` rather than `char` depending on some preprocessor variables. `memcpy()` is oblivious to that and always copies bytes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You probably are mixing ASCII and Unicode strings. If compiling with Unicode setting, then `CString` stores a Unicode string (two bytes per character, in your case each second byte is 0 and thus looks like an ASCII string terminator).

If you want all ASCII:

```
CStringA str = "something";
char* buff = new char[str.GetLength()+1];
memcpy(buff, (LPCSTR)str, str.GetLength() + 1);
```

If you want all Unicode:

```
CStringW str = L"something";
wchar_t* buff = new wchar_t[str.GetLength()+1];
memcpy(buff, (LPCWSTR)str, sizeof(wchar_t)*(str.GetLength() + 1));
```

If you want it working on both settings:

```
CString str = _T("something");
TCHAR* buff = new TCHAR[str.GetLength()+1];
memcpy(buff, (LPCTSTR)str, sizeof(TCHAR) * (str.GetLength() + 1));
```

If you want to convert a Unicode string to an ASCII string:

```
CString str = _T("something");
char* buff = new char[str.GetLength()+1];
memcpy(buff, (LPCSTR)CT2A(str), str.GetLength() + 1);
```

Please also recognize the casts from str to `LPCSTR`, `LPCWSTR` or `LPCTSTR` and the corrected buffer allocation (need multiple characters and not only one).

Also, I am not quite sure if this is really what you need. A `strdup` for example looks much simpler than a `new` + `memcpy`.

Answer (score 3):

You have only allocated memory to hold a `char` variable. To do what you intend, you need to allocate enough memory to hold the complete string.

```
CString str = _T("something");
LPTSTR buff = new TCHAR[(str.GetLength()+1) * sizeof(TCHAR)]; //allocate sufficient memory
memcpy(buff, str, str.GetLength() + 1);
```

Comment: I would suggest `LPTSTR buff = new TCHAR[str.GetLength() + 1]` to alleviate the issue I mentioned under the question.

Comment: Nope, wrong edit, it should be `LPTSTR` instead of `LPSTR`, and you should also multiply `str.GetLength() + 1` by `sizeof(TCHAR)` in your call to `memcpy()`, as Werner does in his answer.

Answer (score 0):

You are

1. Only allocating one `char`, which won't be enough unless the `CString` is empty, and
2. copying the `CString` instance instead of the string it represents.

Try

```
CString str = _T("something");
int size = str.GetLength() + 1;
char* buff = new char[size];
memcpy(buff, str.GetBuffer(), size);
```